# How do I play an audio file with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html5-audio

I'm having a difficult time getting audio to work with jQuery.  I've tried this with both .wav and .ogg formats. (Firefox 19.0.2)

Clicking the <kbd>Start</kbd> button yields:

> TypeError: buzzer.play is not a function

I'm not sure if jQuery selectors return an array, but I've tried the capture the audio file with both:

```
var buzzer = $('buzzer');
```

and

```
var buzzer = $('buzzer')[0];
```

Regardless, I can't get the audio elements to play.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>     
<html>     
    <head>      
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">     
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>    
</head>     

<body>     

<audio id="buzzer" src="buzzer.ogg" type="audio/ogg">Your browser does not support the &#60;audio&#62; element.</audio>    
<form id='sample' action="#" data-ajax="false">    
    <fieldset>    
     <input value="Start" type="submit">    
     </fieldset>    
</form>    
<script type="text/javascript">    

var buzzer = $('buzzer')[0];    

$(document).on('submit', '#sample', function()  {     
    buzzer.play();    
    return false;    
});    

</script>    
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Why would you use a form as a start button ?

Comment: You really should just use `document.getElementById('buzzer')` here... You're not actually *using* jQuery-wrapped elements, you're just taking the long way around to get the native dom element.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You forgot the hash `#` in your ID selector :

```
var buzzer = $('#buzzer')[0];  

$(document).on('submit', '#sample', function()  {     
    buzzer.play();    
    return false;    
});
```

And `document.getElementById('buzzer')` does seem more appropriate!

I'd change the HTML to:

```
<audio id="buzzer" src="buzzer.ogg" type="audio/ogg"></audio>    
<input type="button" value="Start" id="start" />
```

and do:

```
$('#start').on('click', function() {
    $('#buzzer').get(0).play();
});
```

Comment: Or `$('#buzzer')[0].play();` with a nice `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

```
var buzzer = document.getElementById("buzzer");
```

You can also do this:

```
var buzzer = $('audio')[0];
```

And if id `buzzer` is unique (*As it should*) you can also do this - no need of `[0]`

```
var buzzer = $('#buzzer');
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("buzzer");` and btw already suggested by @adeneo

Comment: even after your edit it will not work as suggested by you, you have `Elements` instead of `Element`

Comment: `$('audio')[0]` is not the best approach, I would go for element `ID`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the id to mark your audio tag in your HTML. So,you should add # when your are using the selector.

```
var buzzer = $('#buzzer')[0];
```

besides, you are using id to identify your audio, you can also define your valuable like this:

```
var buzzer = $('#buzzer');
```

don't have to add the [0],[0] means you get the first element.