# Jquery isn't getting called for an audio button

Tags: jquery, html, audio

Trying to make a sound clip play when a button is clicked (this button also links back to another page:

how can I:

1) get it to work?  (works with mouseenter but not with .click())

2) cause a 1 second pause for sound to play before link navigates?

here is my relevant jQuery Code:

```
var beepOne = $("#ding")[0];
$("button[value='reload']")
.click(function() {
beepOne.play();


});
```

and the HTML:

```
<audio preload="auto" id="ding">
    <source src="audio/gameover.mp3"></source>
</audio>

<button class="btn" value="reload" id="snd" onClick="parent.location='../'" />Game Over!<br />Try Again?</button><br>
```

Figured it out, looks like my onClick Property through inline Javascript was wrong.  Removing this and adding it to my jQuery Fixed it and allowed me to have the delay like I wanted for the sound to complete before being redirected.  here is my  **Completed Code** if it helps anyone else:

```
var beepOne = $("#ding")[0];
$("#snd").click(function() {
beepOne.play();
setTimeout(function(){parent.location='/'},1000);

 });
```

Comment: Then you should be posting your own answer and mark it as the correct answer, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var beepOne = $("#ding")[0];
$("#snd").click(function() {
beepOne.play();
 });
```

If you can edit the HTML then probably modifying the html to

```
<audio preload="auto" id="ding" src="audio/gameover.mp3" type="audio/ogg"></audio>
```

might do the trick

Comment: ok I selected the id, but i'm still not hearing it play as expected

Comment: ok this works by itself, I think I see what's happening, my button itself has inline JS which is probably over-riding the JQuery here.  I simply need to put a small delay, then put the parent.location='/' below it.

Answer (score 1):

you should select iD

```
var beepOne = $("#ding")[0];

$("#snd").click(function() {
$('#ding').get(0).play();
 });
```

Old stackoverflow thread semiliar to this

**[How do I play an audio file with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888716/how-do-i-play-an-audio-file-with-jquery)**

Comment: thanks I see the relevance there, trying it out.

Okay so I see how "it should" work, its ignoring the variable and just pulling the 1st #ding element to play.  But its still not working.