# play just the sound corresponding to each div

Tags: jquery

I have some divs, each div have one sound associated.

The stop buttons are hid just appear when the sound is playing.

I want to click in the "play" in each div and play the sound corresponding of the div that has the "play" where i clicked.

But its not working like that, when I click in the play it is playing all sounds.

http://jsfiddle.net/c03zqxw8/2/

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var audioElement = document.getElementById('audio1');
        $('.stop').hide();
        $('.play').click(function() {
            $('.play').hide();
            $('.stop').show();
            audioElement.play();
        });

        $('.stop').click(function() {
            $('.play').show();
            $('.stop').hide();
            audioElement.pause();
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `$(this)`  ,  `prev()` , `next()`  like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('.stop').hide();

        $('.play').click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).next('.stop').show();  $(this).closest('div').find('audio[id^="audio"]').get(0).play();
        });


        $('.stop').click(function() {
            $(this).prev('.play').show();
            $(this).hide();
              $(this).closest('div').find('audio[id^="audio"]').get(0).pause();
        });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/c03zqxw8/3/)

for more info you can take a look at this [How do I play an audio file with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888716/how-do-i-play-an-audio-file-with-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for youar answer. But when you click in the different three plays, the sound is always the same...